# string char being assigned to a char

Tags: c++

Just recently began to get back to programing and started doing some exercises but i keep gettin an error that should be simple to solve but cant seem to solve it...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int numberInts = 3;
    int strSize = 0;
    char interator = 'o';

    string source[3];
    string strTest ("this is a test");

    //source = (string*) malloc (3+1);
    source[0] = "(a+(b*c))"; //abc*+
    source[1] = "((a+b)*(z+x))";
    source[2] = "((a+t)*((b+(a+c))^(c+d)))";

    for(int i=0;i<numberInts;i++)
    {
        strSize = source[i].size();
        for(int j = 0; j < strSize; j++)
        {
            iterator = strTest[0];
            if(source[i][j] == '\(')
            {
                cout<<"\(";
            }

        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

the line "iterator = strTest[0];" gives me  a missing template argument error, and i cant really figure out why cant i assign to a char a position of a string that returns a char...

thanks

Comment: When the error doesn't seem to make sense, double check your variable names. ;)

Comment: It also is wise to avoid variable names using very commonly used word in the standard libraries e.g. iterator. You would have gotten a more obvious error message.

Comment: Avoid `using namespace std;` at all costs. The compiler would have given you a perfectly useful error message but for your namespace directive.

Answer (score 3):

For one thing, you misspelled `iterator` as `interator` when you declared it.

Comment: wow... just wow... lesson #1 in programming remember to check your variables are the same name xD

Comment: I had a dyslexic friend at university, he never got past mispelling 'integer' as 'interger'.

Answer (score 1):

Spelling mistake, your char variable is called interator not iterator.

Answer (score 1):

Switch to [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/). It's error messages are much more specific. It actually catches most spelling mistakes and offers suggestions to what it thinks you might have meant. However it probably wouldn't have caught this as a spelling error because of the iterator template.

You would have seen the following as an error:

```
  testclang.cpp:8:5: error: cannot refer to class template 'iterator'
        without a template argument list
      iterator = 5;
      ^
  In file included from testclang.cpp:1:
  In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.4/iostream:39:
  In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.4/ostream:39:
  In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.4/ios:40:
  In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/char_traits.h:40:
  In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/stl_algobase.h:67:
  /usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/stl_iterator_base_types.h:103:12: note: 
        template is declared here
      struct iterator
```

However without the `using namespace std', this (testclang.cpp):

```
  int main() 
  {
      int interator = 3;
      iterator = 5;
  }
```

When compiled with clang:

```
  clang testclang.cpp
```

produces:

```
testclang.cpp:4:5: error: use of undeclared identifier 'iterator'; did
                          you mean 'interator'?
    iterator = 5;
    ^~~~~~~~
    interator
```